# Retorno negativo de Array.BinarySearch()

Tags: c#, .net, array, busca-binária

Estava precisando fazer uma comparação do gênero de métodos normalmente criados como `inList` ou algo do gênero. Ai pesquisando na documentação da Microsoft, encontrei o `Array.BinarySearch(T[], T)`. Realizei essa operação em meu código e fiquei em dúvida com o retorno que foi **-36**.

```
Array.BinarySearch(new Int32[] { 1, 2, 3, 20, 25, 30, 31, 34, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 6, 12, 14, 17, 18, 27, 48, 4, 10, 11, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 28, 29, 32, 33, 35, 38, 46, 13, 5, 15, 16, 47, 49, 7, 8, 9 }, clalav_lav)
//O valor da variável clalav_lav é 30 no momento
```

Qual o motivo de ele retornar **-36**, se o valor existe no *array*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O motivo é simples, uma busca binária, conforme diz a documentação, só pode ser realizada em uma sequência de dados previamente classificados. Sem essa condição ser atendida o resultado é determinado como negativo, novamente conforme a documentação. No caso apresentado claramente falta uma classificação.

> Searches an entire one-dimensional **sorted array** for a specific element, using the IComparable generic interface implemented by each element of the Array and by the specified object.

Retorno:

> The index of the specified value in the specified array, if value is found; otherwise, a negative number. If value is not found andvalue is less than one or more elements in array, the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value. If value is not found and value is greater than all elements in array, the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of (the index of the last element plus 1). **If this method is called with a non-sorted array, the return value can be incorrect and a negative number could be returned, even if valueis present in array**.

Se compensa fazer a classificação antes de fazer a busca vai depender de uma série de fatores, entre eles, quantas vezes precisará fazer a busca, o tamanho do *array*, recursos disponíveis, etc.

Espero que esteja usando a [versão genérica do método](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Array_BinarySearch__1___0_____0_).

Moral da estória: antes de usar qualquer coisa **leia a documentação**.

Comment: Caramba, no meio da correria, não reparei no ÓBVIO! Muito obrigado.